# Programming an Offset MovingAverage to the left (shifted with -6)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have Problems with programming an offset MA.
I cant get the distance of my current candle(,where the plot is working)to the active candle.

Without knowing this, it obvious comes, that i try to reach at index x<0.

Somebody has ideas?

EDIT: I cant use plot with the offset settings, because that is just visual and i want to use the crossover function with it.( So i have to make sure that the offset value "belongs" to the actual candle)

```
pine_sma_offset(x, y, z) =>
    sum = 0.0
    //candles_until_current = 
    // Überprüfung, ob die aktuelle Kerze eine der letzten 6 Kerzen ist
    candleNumber = last_bar_index-bar_index
    if (candleNumber-1 > z)
        for i = 0 to y - 1
            sum := sum + x[candleNumber - z] / y 
    sum
```

My next idea was:

```
float condition = (last_bar_index - bar_index) > 6 ? 1 : na
if (condition)
crossover_condition := ta.crossover(sma, sma6[-6])
```

But its the same runtime error of invalid number of bars back [-6]

FunFact. The Offset to the right is working with that easily

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the Plot value "Offset"

Plot(x, Offset = z)

Comment: He literally said he couldn't use plot with offset.